# Finding probability that 2 out of 3 students possess a GPA in excess of 2.95?

Tags: probability, statistics

> The grade point averages (GPAs) of a large population of college students are approximately normally distributed with mean 2.4 and standard deviation 0.8.
>
> Suppose that three students are randomly selected from the student body.
> What is the probability that at least two will possess a GPA in excess of
> 2.95?

So I've already worked out that the probability of a student possessing an excess of $2.95$ is $P(Z>0.6875)=0.2483$ (From Standard Normal Table).
And the probability of all 3 students getting an excess of 2.95 is
$$P(\text{all 3 students get an excess of 2.95})=0.2483^3=0.015308412.$$
However, I'm unsure where to find out how 2 of the three possess a $2.95$? Or am I just reading the question wrong and just need to square my answer?

Comment: For future reference, you can find a detailed formatting tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Let $N$ be the number of students that have a GPA greater than or equal to 2.95. Then we want
$$P(N\geq 2) = P(N =2) +P(N=3)$$
where we can add because the events are disjoint. You found $P(N = 3)$. To find $P(N =2)$, you can notice that $N$ follows the binomial distribution with the number of trials equal to 3 and with probability of success $0.2483$. Remember, we are interested in students with GPA greater than or equal to 2.95 (we consider it a success). So we have 
$$P(N =2) = \binom{3}{2}(0.2483)^2(1-0.2483)^{3-2} \approx 0.139.$$